# Show button when form has successfully processed

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap-3

When I use an modal window in Bootstrap the user sees 2 buttons (close and send)

[image]

When the user processes the form the 2 buttons are hidden and an spinner is shown.

[image]

If the form is successfully processed the spinner is hidden and the `Sluiten (closed)` button **should be shown again**, but this button is missing. Any suggestions?

[image]

My code:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal" id="submit_dismiss_table_1'.$i.'" onclick="window.location.reload()">Sluiten</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary betaald_table_1" id="submit_betaald_table_1'.$i.'" alt="'.$i.'">Bewerk</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="submit_spinner_table_1'.$i.'" style="display:none" disabled><i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i></button>


function subform_betaald_table_1(formid)
{
       $("#submit_dismiss_table_1"+formid).remove();
       $("#submit_betaald_table_1"+formid).remove();
       $("#submit_spinner_table_1"+formid).show();

       var postData = $("#betaald_table_1"+formid).serializeArray();
       var formURL='processing/factuur_betaald.php';
        $.ajax({
            url: formURL,
            type: "POST",
            data: postData,
            success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                $('#modal_betaald_table_1'+formid+' .modal-body').html(data);

                $("#submit_spinner_table_1"+formid).remove();
                $("#submit_dismiss_table_1"+formid).show();
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, status, error) {
                console.log(status + ": " + error);
            }
        });
        e.preventDefault();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have removed the button, thats why you cant show it afterwards. You should hide it or toggle it.

```
$('.myButton').hide();

$('.myButton').show();
```

Or use the `.toggle();`

Comment: Ohhh...`remove` is really removing :D Thx!

Comment: Yeah you are actually deleting the element.